# Choosing a date within the past 50 years

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to pick a date past 50 year through `jQuery datepicker` but the `select type of year` shows only limited number of years. I've to repeatedly select year to go back to past years.

Here's `jQuery` script I'm using:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: "-50Y",
    maxDate: "-6Y"
});
```

I'd created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5xQb3/
Please check. I want to show all year in one time not selecting them repeatedly.
Also, I would like to display the date as `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use **yearRange**

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-50:-6"
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xQb3/5/)

Comment: thank you. It works as I want to but there's a little problem if you see. Choose a year from the range and again select year, there's lost of details for previous year. and again I've to reselect years to go back or forth

Answer (score 1):

add `yearRange: "c-50:c-6"` to your instantiation like so

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: "-50Y",
    maxDate: "-6Y",
    yearRange: "c-50:c-6"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
```

and

```
yearRange: 'c-50:c-6',
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xQb3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use Year Range as per your requirement

```
  function loadDatePicker() {
        $('.datePicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-18:-12",
            defaultDate:"-18y-m-d"  // Relative year/month/day
        });
    }
```

Comment: instead of `defaultDate:"-18y-m-d"` only use `defaultDate:"-18y"`